# How to use $htmlAttributes?

Tags: layout, attributes, frontend, html

In `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml:11` there is this code:

```
<html <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $htmlAttributes ?>>
    ...
</html>
```

It looks like we can use layout XML to add attributes to the `<html>` element, but I can't figure out how.

#### How is `$htmlAttributes` used?

---

**Similar functionality**

I presume it works in a similar way to adding attributes to the body or head, but I can't get it working with `<html>` at all.

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>
</body>
```

Comment: According to php storm its the only usage in all places. It doesn't seem to exist anywhere else. How come you're wanting to target the html and no the body?

Comment: I'm not, someone asked how to add attributes to the `<html>` and the only method I could find is to hardcode it in `root.phtml`. But it looks like we *should* be able to do it with layout XML. Unless this was added to the template but the functionality was never added.

Comment: Think thats the legit answer, the functionality doesn't seem to exist anywhere for it.

Comment: Aye, if you want to add that as an answer and if no one adds a method in the next week or so I'll mark it as accepted as I can't find any uses either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though it isn't referenced anywhere, and that is the only usage of it. However I wouldn't recommend using the **HTML** tag to assign anything like this to, but you know this and assign them to **body** instead :)

I guess the only way to actually do it is edit that file. I'd like to say there is an xml way to do it, but at the moment....

Answer (score 2):

Magento adding that class for body using below class
Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page.php

```
  protected function render(HttpResponseInterface $response)
    {
..............
........
 'htmlAttributes' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderElementAttributes($config::ELEMENT_TYPE_HTML),
................
```

It is work same like you are adding for body

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<html>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/> 
    </html>
</page>
```

Output:
http://easycaptures.com/3327274226

Comment: it always returns `html: This element is not expected.` error

Comment: This doesn't work for me either: `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'html': This element is not expected.`

Comment: Check with production mode

Comment: I don't develop in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me :)

```
<html>
    <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/> 
</html>
```

Comment: why you did copy paste as asnwer?

Comment: Just informed this is working for me

Comment: Then like my comment and approved as solution

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it returns this error.  `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'html': This element is not expected.`

Answer (score 0):

I use Magento 2.2 and it doesnt work for me either (dev mode), This is probably a bug. As a patch until this is fixed you can edit:

magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_merged.xsd

Add under root element (you'll see that the other schema tags of head/body/elements are also there):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/head.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/body.xsd"/>
    <!--ADD THE NEXT LINE-->
    <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/html.xsd"/>
```

Then you should add under xs:complexType tag with name="layoutType" (around line 33) under 'xs:choice' tag >> the element tag for that html schema (htmlType):

```
<xs:complexType name="layoutType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Layout Type definition
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="referenceContainer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="container" type="containerType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="update" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="remove" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="move" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="block" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="referenceBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="body" type="bodyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="head" type="headType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <!--ADD THE NEXT LINE-->
        <xs:element name="html" type="htmlType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Then it should work by adding the the proper xml in any xml layout file, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <html>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter" />
    </html>
</page>
```